# Javascript show and hide div with animation

Tags: jquery

I'm not the only one with this problem. I tried many solution that I found on this forum, but without any succes. What am I doing wrong?

What I want to achieve:
Once a div opened and a user clicks on a other div that this div opens with same animation, but first the other div closes with reverse animation. I hope this explanation is clear.

Heres my code: (HTML)

```js
    $('a').click(function () {
        var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
        $(itemID).slideToggle({
          direction: "up"
        }, 300);
        return false;
      });
```

```css
#click-01{
      background: #fd6569;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 22px;
      margin:0;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    #click-02{
      background: #fda988;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 22px;
      margin:0;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    #click-03{
      background: #87cba0;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 22px;
      margin:0;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .close{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a href="#click-01">01</a>
    <a href="#click-02">02</a>
    <a href="#click-03">03</a>
      <div id="click-01" class="close">
        <p>
          item-01
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="click-02" class="close">
        <p>
          item-02
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="click-03" class="close">
        <p>
          item-03
        </p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using jQuery's [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function. Also, instead of using `slideToggle`, use `hide` and `show`.

I have modified parts of your snippet and shown a working demo, below.

```js
        $('a').click(function () {
            var itemID = $(this).attr('href');
            $( "div" ).not( itemID ).hide({
              direction: "up"
            }, 300);
            $(itemID).show({
              direction: "down"
            }, 300);
            return false;
          });
```

```css
#click-01{
          background: #fd6569;
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 16px;
          line-height: 22px;
          margin:0;
          padding: 20px;
        }
        #click-02{
          background: #fda988;
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 16px;
          line-height: 22px;
          margin:0;
          padding: 20px;
        }
        #click-03{
          background: #87cba0;
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 16px;
          line-height: 22px;
          margin:0;
          padding: 20px;
        }
        .close{
          display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <a href="#click-01">01</a>
        <a href="#click-02">02</a>
        <a href="#click-03">03</a>
          <div id="click-01" class="close">
            <p>
              item-01
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="click-02" class="close">
            <p>
              item-02
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="click-03" class="close">
            <p>
              item-03
            </p>
          </div>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lucas If it solved your question, don't forget to mark the question as solved